# How to create a "private" Jenkins job which cannot be called directly, but only from another job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

Jenkins allows **jobs chaining** - one job calls another. We may configure it in the *Trigger/call builds on other projects* section.

Is it possible to create a "private" Jenkins job, which can be called **only from within** another job and **never directly**?

The use case is to avoid users launching by mistake an internal job which is mentioned to be used *only* as one of the steps in a job chain. All users are trusted, it is meant as a protection against a mistake.

Comment: I don't think so, manually triggering the build is not something that can be disabled, at least not within the job configuration. What would you need this for?

Answer (score 0):

Add to beginning of your downstream/protected job.
Please note that this requires like 3 approvals if you run your scripts in sandbox.

```
if (currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause) == null) {
    throw new SecurityException("can be only triggered from upstream")
}
```

For more information [the example I've based on](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/get-build-cause/getBuildCause.groovy) and [the actual Cause class](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Cause.java).